# Using jQuery to parse large data set on categories & sub-categories

Tags: jquery, html, xml, webforms

I'm in the early stages of a web project that will involved a very large (5000+) set of categories, sub-categories & sub-sub-categories that need to be loaded into a html form.

I'm considering storing the data in an XML file and then using jQuery to load into the form, **and only grab the sub-categories when requested** (any ways to optimize this??). I'm using Zend Framework, so I thought loading from MySQL database each time would slow the application down greatly.

My question is would there be any drawbacks to this method, esp. as the category listings need to be referred to in the SQL database?

Many thanks,

Adam

Comment: Intranet? If you have the luxury to tell your users what browser/plugin to use, you could use the build in database in Chrome, or use Google Gears' database.

Comment: Your JavaScript engine will love you forever if you could store the data in JSON format instead of XML. It's infinitely quicker to parse and even easier (if that's possible) to traverse.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you can do to in order to archive good performance/response time here.

1. Use JSON instead of XML. XML *may* take more bandwidth and it *will* take way longer to parse, especially with such a huge data set
2. Cache the file on the server and re-generate on every write, unless you expect more writes then reads, this will improve performance a lot
3. For more client side responsiveness you could load the data only when needed, you could deploy a file structure on the server for this, therefore you'll need to have subdirectories which then contain the sub categories .json files etc. this way you can minimize the data transfered to the client, you could also optimize the caching to only re-generate changed parts of the tree.

You main concern here should probably be the front end, since loading 5000+ categories into a form at once would take very very long, so most of the structures on the back end are just for speeding up the client, database and zend should take care of the normal caching on their own.

Comment: Thanks Ivo.. with regards to point 2, how would I cache a json file & re-generate?

Comment: Zend seems to have JSON support: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.basics.html As soon as you write to the database you will A) have to find out what changes (in case you're going with the tree approach) and then B) format that data into associative arrays, feed it to `Zend_Json::encode` and then write the return value to the file on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you have a large dataset, consider generating your form's markup using **[XSLT transformations](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_intro.asp).**  I have faced a similar situation and used XSLT/Xpath to **great advantages**.

Here's a [sample](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_ex1) that should show you XSLT's raw power for such cases.